# Retrofit 2.0 cancel a Call object

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, request-cancelling

Has anyone played around with [Retrofit 2.0](https://github.com/square/retrofit), specifically the [Call.cancel()](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--) method?

When is the best time to trigger that?  I have tried calling it in `onStop()` of a `Fragment` but have run into some issues with a call being cancelled when the screen display gets turned off.  Also I tried calling it in `onDestroy()` of a `Fragment` but this method does not cancel a call that get triggered in a `ViewPager` ( for example switching between tabs)

Does anyone have a working example of this?

I have attempted to implement this my Loop repo :
https://github.com/lawloretienne/Loop

Answer (score 11):

The 'right' place will largely depend on your specific use-cases. As you've discovered, there's unlikely to be a one-size-fits-all solution. Here are a couple things to consider based on your stated needs:

---

Is cancellation of network requests when the screen is switched off a big problem for your app? Is a user likely to turn the screen off while expecting the app to continue functioning?

- If not, you are safe to use `onStop`, as you've already described.
- If so, you can move your network requests to a class that lives outside the `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycles (e.g. using a singleton network request manager, or relying more on `Service` subclasses). You will then be able to handle cancellations on a case-by-case basis. For example, you would still be able to cancel requests inside lifecycle callbacks whenever you wanted to (by signaling this to the manager), but you wouldn't be *required* to.

---

With respect to cancelling network requests triggered by `Fragments` in a `ViewPager`, you might want to implement your own faux-lifecycle methods. Here's [a great pattern I've used a couple of times](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/). The gist is as follows:

- Have all `Fragments` used by the `ViewPager` implement an interface that contains 'fake' versions of the lifecycle methods you care about.

Example:

```
public interface FragmentLifecycle {
    public void onStartFragment();
    public void onStopFragment();
}
```

- Set an `OnPageChangeListener` on your `ViewPager`, and track the current page inside it. Whenever the page changes, call the appropriate methods on the incoming/outgoing fragments.

Example:

```
private OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {
        final FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle) pageAdapter.getItem(newPosition);
        fragmentToShow.onStartFragment();

        final FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle)pageAdapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        // Cancel network requests inside this callback. It
        // corresponds to the current page moving off-screen.
        fragmentToHide.onStopFragment(); 

        currentPosition = newPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // no-op
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // no-op
    }
};
```

(I updated the linked example to use `onStart`/`onStop` since you already mentioned that lifecycle pair in your question.)

Hopefully that gives you some ideas as to how best to use the new cancellation features in Retrofit 2! Let us know what you come up with.

Comment: I have it working in `onDestroyView()` . https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/5b8529f536bd0c5f72f7

But my problem is there are instances where a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown so that Call object never gets cancelled.

This of course defeats the purpose of the cancelling mechanism if it can't happen every time.  Apparently there is some kind of Strictmode issue in OKHttp.  There is an issue filed here
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1592

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a good way to avoid that until it's patched in OkHttp unfortunately. You'd need to fall back on a mechanism to manually ignore the results of calls that were supposed to be cancelled, but this is the same solution you would use without Call.cancel() anyway.

Comment: In the meantime I am wrapping `Call.cancel()` in an `AsyncTask`.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1592#issuecomment-143309765

Answer (score 1):

Have you try **UserVisibleHint**?

```
   @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
                // fragment visible to user
        }else{
           // fragment invisible 
           // you can call Call.cancel() here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even so, Call.cancel() might still throw an exception because of the bug in OKHttp.

Comment: Can you log exception?

Comment: @KishanVaghela,I think the bug toobsco42  said is this: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1592

Comment: @toobsco42 this exception is fixed now!